# video element to go below previous element if no enough space left on viewport

Tags: html, css

I am trying to dynamically add video element to a div with each video element has 50vh width. So technically after ever 2 video elements, 3rd video element would be below to the left of screen.

I have tried:

```
.views-container {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 0;
}

.video-inset {
    outline: unset;
    position: relative;
    margin:0; 
    padding:0;
}

<div class="views-container background-black" id="container"></div>
```

And JS

```
// Current condition is for 3 video elements but could be more
// height width added dynamically and could be different depending on number of elements
// 3 video elements in a row (33.33vw width) if greater than 15 video elements

const container = document.getElementById('container')

const video = document.createElement('video');
video.style.height = 50+"vh"
video.style.width = 50+"vw"

container.append(video);
```

It works fine only until 2 containers. Please help.

Comment: try to use Bootstrap Grid System. It handles everything.
Link: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: @Qiimiia, But I need custom size depending on number of video elements -- Just updated question.

Comment: You can add custom height to your columns and can have 2, 3, 4, 6, or 12 columns on a row based on your need.

Comment: @Qiimiia Okay thanks, I will try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `display: grid;` on the `.views-container`. I have used a width and height of `50vw` and `50vh`. You need to change the `2` (the number of columns) in `repeat(2, 1fr)` to another number.

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container');

let n = 20;  //Total number of videos

for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
  const video = document.createElement('video');
  if(n > 15){
  container.style.gridTemplateColumns = "repeat(3, 1fr)";
    video.style.height = "33.33vh";
    video.style.width = "33.33vw";
  } else{
    video.style.height = "50vh";
    video.style.width = "50vw";
  }
  video.src = "https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-videos/flower.webm"
  container.append(video);
}
```

```css
.views-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr)
}


.video-inset {
  outline: unset;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="views-container background-black" id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this what I was looking for. Tested and worked.